# Randomly choose between classes and apply them to div upon page load?

Tags: css, random, figure

**Is this Possible?:** Upon page load, for any `<figure>` that has a class called '`.random`' will randomly assign its image an element that'll be between `float:left;` or `float:right;`.

I have set up a [jsfiddle][1].
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/qc4kypvr/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

```
function randomize() {
    var elts = document.querySelectorAll('figure.random');
    var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(elts);
    array.forEach(function(elt) {
        elt.style.float = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'left' : 'right';
    });
}
```

Run that on page load.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! but is @Vitorino Fernandes more efficient or does it make no difference?

Comment: I doubt if there is any difference in efficiency worth worrying about. The major difference is that he uses jQuery.

Comment: ah I see. in that case, would you mind taking a look at the jsfiddle? I can't seem to get it to work... http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/bnmwcgwr/

Comment: would like the image to be on either the right or left side within the figure's width.

Comment: In that case you have to put the `float` on the image, not the `figure`. See http://jsfiddle.net/bnmwcgwr/8/. Beyond this, feel free to fiddle with it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/qc4kypvr/2/

```
$('.random').css("float", function () {
  var floats = ["left", "right"];
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * floats.length);
  return floats[rand];
});
```